# Jmeter Error sent email on gmail

Tags: java, jmeter

today i'm researching about the **jmeter**.

1. connect the gmail
2. login
3. send email

I passed 2 step and got error "*`java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.google.com`*" on step 3

**Login :**
[image]

**Send Email :**[image]

I connected the link "**mail.google.com**" on the website.

Can somebody teach me what am i wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) instead of simulating sending an email using web interface.

The relevant configuration would be:

- Server: `smtp.googlemail.com`
- Port: `587`
- Address from: your Gmail address
- Address to: recipient address(es)
- Check "Use Auth" and provide your **full** GMail username and password
- Tick "Use StarTLS" radiobutton

Other fields are pretty much self-explanatory

[image: GMail SMTP]

References:

- [Set up Gmail with Outlook, Apple Mail, or other mail clients](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&rd=1)
- [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It worked for me  and thanks for your document.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T. how can i pass a value to a textbox of a website using jmeter? .(example the textbox's website dont have "name")can i pass value by css ? can you share for me some infomation ? Thansk

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer you will like, but you should not be pointing any performance testing tool at a server you do not own, control or manage (or have permission from the people who do).  In addition, Google's own end user agreement prohibits this behavior, supporting automation only with their published API set.  License-wise and ethically, this is a problematic set of behavior for performance testing.

If you wish to experiment, then consider setting up a LAMP stack box inside of your own domain/control with an SMTP relay, pointing to mailbox destinations on that server.  If you must test routing then setup two email servers with destinations on the opposite host (easy with two virtual machines).

Note, SMTP supports direct addressing, such as [name]@[host|IP address] so you can control directly any email routing to outside mailboxes accidentally and SPAMming individuals or organizations.  This also avoids the problem of clogging up an SMTP relay with thousands of messages undeliverable due to lack of a valid address - this last condition will slow all email delivery for an organization and if not addressed can grind delivery to a halt before the first undeliverable messages start failing out after the delivery timeout is reached which is typically around 72 hours.